# How to build a relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get all of ProductSpecData, those products that belong to a specific category.

For example:

```
$category->products() ... query
```

I need all the ProductSpecData models, but I need to avoid replication.
I'm talking about the unique method (`->unique()`)

[image: Database Design]

I do not know how to write a query to the database. I also don't know how to implement this using Eloquent. I hope for your help.

Comment: your question is unclear. What data are you getting and what data do you want to get ? can you add an example to your question (use Edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69346829/edit)

Comment: @n69s Okay, Sir... Now you can check

Comment: Do you already have your Eloquent models specified? If so, could you add those to your question? If not, please check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to add a relation to existed table using Laravel migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->dropForeign('products_category_id_foreign');
    });
}
```

For more information check Laravel migration documentation about foreign Id: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId